# How to parse The following JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am making a web app for nokia S40 platform . I am calling a web service using Javascript that returns the Following JSON

```
{ "status_code": 200, "status_txt": "OK", "data": { "expand": [ { "short_url": "http:\/\/bit.ly\/msapps", "long_url": "http:\/\/www.microsoft.com\/web\/gallery\/?wt.mc_id=soc-in-wag-msp-M389", "user_hash": "gbL9jV", "global_hash": "eHgpGh" } ] } }
```

I want to obtain the "short_url" and "long_url " values

I am using **eval** as `var obj = eval ("(" + xmlhttp.responseText + ")");`

where **xmlhttp.responseText** conatains the JSON response. 
Please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tried this and worked

```
 var s = '{ "status_code": 200, "status_txt": "OK", "data": { "expand": [ { "short_url": "http://bit.ly/msapps", "long_url": "http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/?wt.mc_id=soc-in-wag-msp-M389", "user_hash": "gbL9jV", "global_hash": "eHgpGh" } ] } } '

 var d = JSON.parse(s);
 console.log(d.data.expand[0].short_url);
 console.log(d.data.expand[0].long_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
JSON.parse('{ "status_code": 200, "status_txt": "OK", "data": { "expand": [ { "short_url": "http:\/\/bit.ly\/msapps", "long_url": "http:\/\/www.microsoft.com\/web\/gallery\/?wt.mc_id=soc-in-wag-msp-M389", "user_hash": "gbL9jV", "global_hash": "eHgpGh" } ] } }').data.expand[0].short_url
```

returns "http://bit.ly/msapps"

Answer (score -3):

How about this

```
var json = "{}" // Your JSON string
json = new Function('return ' + json)();
console.log(json.data.expand[0].short_url, json.data.expand[0].long_url);
```

Comment: This is a very bad habit to get into, because in some circumstances it can compromise security. For example, suppose you have javascript code in your server reading JSON from the client. If you do it this way, the client can send any javascript string, and it will run on the server.